# How do we capture SMDR\CDR from PBX?

Tags: telephony, pabx

I just try to build Call Monitor system that reading SMDR\CDR from my PABX through Serial port or IP. So that I can produce some reports from that data. I know data output format is different from each manufacturer, so how can we handle this problem? Is there any libraries or sample projects that easy to get started?

Comment: Did you find anything useful? At least any documentation about the data?

Comment: @bojan, I haven't found it yet.

Comment: try a solution like "pbx data logger". It will capture, parse data and store it to your database. Then you can use this parsed data and build any reports.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free tool to capture SMDR info for you, if that is the route you wish to take.

[Simple SMDR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplesmdr/)

Answer (score 0):

I have written parser for several output formats from many different vendors and actually there are often very easy the read and "parse" the data because it is well defined ASCII data (mostly, sometimes in bianry format but still its very well defined), I havent found any librarys to ease the task of getting hold of the data, but the hard part has always been to figure out how to intepret different vendors values.
I can try to provide some resources if you can tell me what pabx you are targeting.

Comment: @wendelstam, I would think on Panasonic. Thanks

Comment: too bad, I have no experience with panasonic.